# how to convert a string to json, but without quotes, by php jsonencode

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have this `PHP Code...`

```
foreach($valoresa as $cada)
    $listaDatos[$c++] = array('Date.UTC(' . date("Y", strtotime($cada['reading_date'])) . ',' . date("m", strtotime($cada['reading_date'])) . ',' . date("d", strtotime($cada['reading_date'])) . ',' . date("H", strtotime($cada['reading_date'])) . ',' . date("i", strtotime($cada['reading_date'])) . ',' . date("s", strtotime($cada['reading_date'])) . ')', floatval($cada['value']));
```

Then mixing `JS` and `PHP`:

```
{
    name: '<?php echo $nombreDato; ?>',
    yAxis: <?php echo $yAxis++; ?>,
    data: <?php echo json_encode($listaDatos); ?>
},
```

This is `the result`:

```
data: [["Date.UTC(2013,06,26,16,03,35)",0],["Date.UTC(2013,06,26,16,04,35)",1],["Date.UTC(2013,06,26,16,06,35)",0]]
```

I want this: `(Without any quote)`

```
data: [[Date.UTC(2013,06,26,16,03,35),0],[Date.UTC(2013,06,26,16,04,35),1],[Date.UTC(2013,06,26,16,06,35),0]]
```

Why am I do this? If I do something like this:

```
foreach($valores01 as $cada)
    $listaDatos[$c++] = array(strtotime($cada['reading_date']) * 1000, floatval($cada['value']));
```

The `highcharts` is recognizing the data date, 2 hours earlier than original, and I just want to test with `Date.UTC()` because original examples of `highcharts` do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JNkRR/

**FIXED:**

I fixed with the @nnnnnn tip, it very simple, i was thinking about a any json php function or something, but it was simplier using `str_replace()` php function:

```
<?php
    $datosFinales = json_encode($listaDatos);
?>
{
    name: '<?php echo $nombreDato; ?>',
    yAxis: <?php echo $yAxis++; ?>,
    data: <?php echo str_replace("\"", "", $datosFinales); ?>
},
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support quotes.

Comment: So, it is doing by itself, how can I do in order to remove those quotes.

Comment: You could do a string replace in your PHP code to change each `"` to an empty-string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent quoting of certain values with PHP json\_encode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330944/prevent-quoting-of-certain-values-with-php-json-encode)

Comment: Well JSON does not support calling methods/functions so how would it be possible to begin with?

Comment: @nnnnnn well thanks, I didn't realize that simple solution, I've just did it, thank you... u.u, now I got working again my heavy machinery xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with the @nnnnnn tip, it very simple, i was thinking about a any json php function or something, but it was simplier using str_replace() php function:

```php
<?php
    $datosFinales = json_encode($listaDatos);
?>
{
    name: '<?php echo $nombreDato; ?>',
    yAxis: <?php echo $yAxis++; ?>,
    data: <?php echo str_replace("\"", "", $datosFinales); ?>
},
```