# Get php to output Json with out quotes so that javascript will see it as a object

Tags: php, javascript, json

Here is the problem I am having I would like to be able to output a javascript object like this

```
{
    id : "title",
    name : "Title",
    field : "title",
    width : 200,
    cssClass : "cell-title",
    editor : Slick.Editors.Text
}
```

Notice that the **editor : Slick.Editors.Text** is not in quotes of any kind.

I can output this... but I can't seem to get php to not put quotes around Slick.Editor.Text

```
{"id":"title","name":"Title","field":"title","width":200,"cssClass":"cell-title","editor":"Slick.Editors.Text"}
```

Here is the php code i am using to output this string.

```
public function creatColumn($id, $name, $field, $width, $cssClass, $editor = null) {
    $obj = (object) array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name, 'field'=>$field, 'width'=>$width, 'cssClass'=> $cssClass, 'editor' => $editor);
    return json_encode($obj);
}
```

Is there a way to output a php json object to php doesn't quote the string?

Comment: that would not be JSON, so, no. preg_replace maybe...

Comment: I found this which looks like what you want:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330944/prevent-quoting-of-certain-values-with-php-json-encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hacky, but you could do:

```
public function creatColumn($id, $name, $field, $width, $cssClass, $editor = null) {
  $obj = (object) array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name, 'field'=>$field, 'width'=>$width, 'cssClass'=> $cssClass);
  $json = json_encode($obj);
  return str_replace('}', '"editor":'.$editor.' }', $json);
}
```